# Swift 'does not have a member named'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, var, let

Is there a solution for this problem ?

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    let collectionFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: collectionFlowLayout)
}
```

xcode gives me the following error

```
ViewController.swift: 'ViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'collectionFlowLayout'
```

i could make it an optional and initialise it in the init method, but i'm looking for a way to make the collectionview a let and not a var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign initial values to constant member variables in your initializer.  There's no need to make it a `var` or optional.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    let collectionFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    let collectionView : UICollectionView

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?)
    {
        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, 
                                collectionViewLayout: self.collectionFlowLayout);

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil);
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting let variables(constants) in the init method:

```
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    let collectionFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
    let collectionView: UICollectionView! 

    init() {
        super.init()
        self.collectionFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: collectionFlowLayout)
    }
}
```

We can access the let variables with self.

Hope that it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

At that point there is not `collectionFlowLayout` created so it complains that there is no member named like that.

The solution can be as you mentioned to make it optional and initialise it in init or you can do this:

```
let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
```

Comment: @MehulThakkar I tried your cade in xCode 6.1 and it doesn't work.